# Troubleshooting Dimmer Circuit

Tags: triac, troubleshooting

First off I do apologize for my ignorance, 
I know very little on the topic so please be patient.

I have one of these that are broken 
http://www.smartliving.com.au/z-wave-in-line-dimmer.html

- Its a Z-Wave dimmer that plugs into a lamp
- It enabled remote switching and dimming of a lamp plugged into it
- The micro-electronics portion of the circuit is fine and I can switch the device on and off remotely (Based on the onboard LED correctly showing status)
- I did a visual inspection on the circuit and cant see anything obvious wrong
- All the capacitors appear fine to me

At this stage I believe its the high voltage portion of the circuit that has a problem.

1. What is this coil cylindrical thing on the board?
2. How do I test it with a multi meter?
3. I tested the BT139 600e triac, if I do a continuity test across the first and third leg I get a closed circuit (My MM beeps), could this be my issue?
4. Any other common problems I should check to troubleshoot a dimmer?

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: THe coil is likely used for pulse triggering the Triac like here except without D1 perhaps https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2zNq.png The coil has 0 DC R on 1st and 3rd pin then. Is it stuck ON or OFF? Why did that happen?

Comment: This may explain how it works. http://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/microcontroller-controlled-light-dimmer.html But to debug takes skill on look for signs of xtal clock, pulses, life etc using Vdc, Vac on DMM or a scope.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 the dimmer never switches on a light, so I guess its stuck off. Dont understand the why did that happen question?

Comment: Did you see it fail?

Comment: I did not, bought a bunch of things from someone over ebay, it was dead on arrival, the other one I got worked fine. They claim it worked when they last used it.  It did cross my mind that I should be focusing my attention differently if it truly was something that broke because of rough handling during shipping.

Comment: If you have two copies of a circuit, one working and one not, the obvious first step is to compare readings between them to see which ones differ.

Comment: @DaveTweed I was hoping not to have to dismantle the working one if I can do some basic troubleshooting first

Comment: Do you know how to create a schematic diagram from a circuit board?

Comment: @DaveTweed like fritzing the circuit? Have mocked up some super basic circuits yes. 
Sorry if the post seemed too general, however I had 3 very specific questions (See points #1 - 3) just getting guidance on those 3 basic questions will get a resolved from me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
There are 2 possibilities for the coil and after reflection ( dim illumination... pun intended) I am changing my mind.  I think pin 1 <>3 are shorted.

To confirm ; purpose of coil as { gate trigger or surge current line filter}

> if coil traces are in series with the  brown line voltage wire,
>   ...  then it is a line filter in series with the LOAD
>   ... then wick solder from Triac
>    ... and carefully remove without hole damage from excessive soldering time.
>   ... then retest Triac to confirm short circuit failure ( or not)

( re-linked [explanation](http://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/microcontroller-controlled-light-dimmer.html) of similar unit design except intead of Arduino this possible a ST uC. )

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to ask questions and answering with so much detail.
I swopped out the triac and its fixed :)
You sir are a legend, today I stood on the shoulders of a giant!

Comment: You are one of the few to say this and I appreciate the recognition. THis is a simple problem for most Sr EE's in retrospect for me.  Note "Swap" is the correct spelling which with my poor typing skills is my achilles heel. Your sincerity is appreciated more than than some Admins who vote mine often with -1 for ego issues and my less spectacular answers